# Give values instead of references to lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

The problem is simple, but I couldn't find the solution to it after searching for a while, so here goes my question:

How do I pass the value of a variable into a lambda function instead of the references to it?

To give you an example:

```
my_lambdas = []

for i in range(5):
    my_lambdas.append(lambda: print(i))

for l in my_lambdas:
    l()
```

Running the above code results in 5 printed '4's. I'm guessing this happens because the lambdas are being run after variable i is set to 4.

I would like it to print 0 to 4. How can I achieve this?

Edit: I need a solution using lambdas and iteration.

Comment: my_lambdas = []
    
    for i in range(5):
        my_lambdas.append((lambda x: (lambda: x))(i))
    
    for l in my_lambdas: l()

This puts another closure inside the for loop closure to pin the reference

Comment: I had a solution using a function, but it amounts to the same thing, adding another level of scope.

Comment: @prM: and that's not practical at all. `lambda i=i: print(i)` binds the value as a keyword argument.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how is that "not practical at all"?

Comment: @prM: it is rather unreadable, don't you think?

Comment: @MartijnPieters and it's "not practical at all"? I love your definition.